# Zooming the graphics in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, zooming

I use `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` in order to draw graphics. 
How can I organize zoom-in and zoom-out (during zooming in scrolls should appear and while zooming out scrolls should disappear)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QGraphicsView::scale(qreal, qreal)

e.g. 
QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView (parent);
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->addText("Hello World");
view->setScene(scene);
view->show();
view->resize(100,100);

// coll from some slot to see the effect
view->scale(2,2);   //zoom in
view->scale(.5,.5); //zoom out
```

Scroll-bars will disappear automatically if scene fits into the size of view.

Regards,
Valentin